# Get coordinates after rotation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol which contains a rectangle and 2 ellipses on the left and right edge of the rectangle. 
I am intrested in finding out the coordinates of the user control after a translate and rotation rendertransform has occured.

The user control is contained in a canvas.

EDIT:
After searching the internet for a while i was able to find the answer to my question here http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/136759/305241.aspx so I thought i'd post the link for other people having this issue.

I've marked Tomas Petricek's post as an answer because it was the closest one to the solution.

Comment: Your link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to implement the calculation yourself, then you can use the following method to calculate a location of a point after rotation (by a specified number of degrees):

```
public Point RotatePoint(float angle, Point pt) { 
   var a = angle * System.Math.PI / 180.0;
   float cosa = Math.Cos(a), sina = Math.Sin(a);
   return new Point(pt.X * cosa - pt.Y * sina, pt.X * sina + pt.Y * cosa);
}
```

In general, you can represent transformations as matrices. To compose transformations, you'd just multiply the matrices, so this is a very composable solution. The matrix to represent rotation contains the *sin* and *cos* values from the method above. See [Rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) (and [Transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)) on Wikipedia.

Comment: This is the snippet i came up with. `code Point coordsAfterRotation = new Point(0, 0); double angle = sender.rotatedAngle * Math.PI / 180; coordsAfterRotation.X = (Canvas.GetLeft(sender) + sender.translatedX) * Math.Cos(angle) - (Canvas.GetTop(sender) + sender.translatedY) * Math.Sin(angle); coordsAfterRotation.Y = (Canvas.GetLeft(sender) + sender.translatedX) * Math.Sin(angle) + (Canvas.GetTop(sender) + sender.translatedY) * Math.Cos(angle); Point testRectCoords = new Point(coordsAfterRotation.X, coordsAfterRotation.Y); `

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to mark the code properly. The reason i added the translated x and translated y is because i wanted to add the translation also. Because the user can move and rotate the user control using touch gestures. The variable sender is the mentioned user control

Comment: but you don't say where are the coordinates of the center of rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You rotate a 2D point [4,6] 36 degrees around the origin. What is the new location of the point?

Solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Origin of the point
            Point myPoint = new Point(4, 6);
            // Degrees to rotate the point
            float degree = 36.0F;

            PointF newPoint = RotatePoint(degree, myPoint);

            System.Console.WriteLine(newPoint.ToString());
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static PointF RotatePoint(float angle, Point pt)
        {
            var a = angle * System.Math.PI / 180.0;
            float cosa = (float)Math.Cos(a);
            float sina = (float)Math.Sin(a);
            PointF newPoint = new PointF((pt.X * cosa - pt.Y * sina), (pt.X * sina + pt.Y * cosa));
            return newPoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods for those who want to rotate around non zero center:

```
public static class VectorExtentions
{
    public static Point Rotate(this Point pt, double angle, Point center)
    {
        Vector v = new Vector(pt.X - center.X, pt.Y - center.Y).Rotate(angle);
        return new Point(v.X + center.X, v.Y + center.Y);
    }

    public static Vector Rotate(this Vector v, double degrees)
    {
        return v.RotateRadians(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    public static Vector RotateRadians(this Vector v, double radians)
    {
        double ca = Math.Cos(radians);
        double sa = Math.Sin(radians);
        return new Vector(ca * v.X - sa * v.Y, sa * v.X + ca * v.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.generaltransform.transform.aspx) method of the RotateTransform object - give it the point with coordinates you wish to transform and it will rotate it.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and unfortunatley i still wasn't able to get the right coordinates.

Comment: @Nashulmic What is the problem - it doesn't calculate correct coordinates? Do you use THE SAME transform object as in the XAML (or with the same parameters)?

Comment: I've added a manipulation processor to the user control in the user control itself. What i am trying to do is to determine the new coordinates of the point that used to be the top left corner of the user control. I use (Canvas.GetLeft(sender),Canvas.GetTop(sender)) to determine the initial coordinates of the user control and after that i apply the total translate and the total rotation angle to this point. Sender is the variable for the user control