# C# How to get the Points of transformed Geometry

Tags: c#, geometry, transform

I am working with C# Geometry.

I encountered a problem when using Transform of Geometry.

For example, A RectangleGeometry with TopLeft point (20,25) and BottomRight point (50,60) is applied with RotateTransform of 30 degree by the centre of the rectangle.

After transformation, how could I get back the transformed TopLeft point and BottomRight point?

The library only provide the renderbounds which is the rectangle boundary of the whole geomeyry. But how could I get back the transformed points corresponding to the original TopLeft and BottomRight point?

Thank you so much.

Comment: RotateTransform by -30 degrees?

Comment: any degree. it is just an example

Comment: If you hold a rectangle and apply a rotation on it by X degrees, you can get the original coordinates by rotation the new coordinates by -X degrees...

Comment: no Shai, he means how to get the new TopLeft and BottomRight after the transformation. You could calculate it manually, but that's probably not what you're looking for

Comment: What's so hard about calculating a simple matrix multiplication? one can find 1001 examples on google for that.

Comment: calculation is not so hard. I think using Math.Atan is already enough... but just want to know if the C# library provided.

Thanks All.

Comment: It seems a duplicate to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180685/get-coordinates-after-rotation