# Applying css3 rotation around center of group after previous local rotations around center of individual item

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

I have a div with many items that can be dragged around.
I can select and group multiple items and then rotate them all together as a group. That works all well, but only if the individual items had zero rotation applied to them previously.

Problems happen if individual items had local rotations applied to them previously. In such case the group rotation has deviations in the positions of the items and doesnt work well.

I think the problem is that local individual rotations of each item are done with transform-origin set to 50% 50% the center of the individual item. Whereas rotating each of those items around the center of a group that include them has a new transform-origin that we set to the center of the group obviously.

If, lets say, item1 had a local rotation of 45 degrees done first. And then it was grouped with other items and a group rotation of 30 degrees was applied to the group. Then item1 would have to in total have 45 degrees of rotation in relation to itself and 30 degrees in relation to center of group. The problem is how do we implement this.

Rotation in css3 only admits one transform-origin. I have tried matrices and many ways but results still dont come well if items had previous rotations on them. Everything works great if items had zero rotations before. Then group rotates great around its center. But if individual items had local rotations then things break down when rotating the entire group.

So the question is, how can we combine two rotations (or any other two transformations) on the very same item which employ different transform-origins (say one local around its own center and next one around center of large group that includes that item).

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate multiple transform-origins by using a translate() before and one after. Here's an example: http://lea.verou.me/css-4d/#circle-demo-3 (might take a while to load)

Keep in mind that every transform function changes the entire coordinate system, and everything will become easier to understand.

Comment: thank you very much, your example is awesome, fantastic, do you have any advice about how to find the amount to translate? as thats my main issue, I'm trying to employ trigonometry equations to find the translation of a point when doing x rotation but no luck so far :) ive been looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180685/get-coordinates-after-rotation  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043391/html5-canvas-calculating-a-x-y-point-when-rotated

Comment: In this particular example, the amount is the radius of the circle on which the smiley moves. The first rotation rotates the system of coordinates of the smiley, the translation moves it along the new post-rotation `x-axis` and the second rotation rotates back the rotated and then moved coordinate system.